# Traverse directed edges recursively with OrientDB

Tags: graph-databases, orientdb

I am trying to recursively traverse outbound edges from a given node, but not the inbound ones. I want both  out edges and out vertices in the result of my query.

In the following graph, starting from (a), I need (a), (b), (c), (d), (e), including the edges, but not the part after (c), which is `<-- (x)`

```
(a) -->  (b) --> (c) <-- (x)
 ˙-->  (d) --> (e)
```

If I try doing the following, then it traverses everything recursively, irrespective of edge direction, thus also returning (x):

```
TRAVERSE * FROM (SELECT FROM a) LIMIT -1`
```

If I don`t traverse *, but`outE()`, it only retrieves the starting node and its direct neighbours: (a), (b), (d), so it does not do recursion.

```
traverse outE() from (SELECT FROM a) LIMIT -1
```

I also tried to follow the documentation at [here](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.0/orientdb.wiki/SQL-Traverse.html#using-traverse-with-graph-model-and-api), and traversed `V.out, E.in` but it only returns (a) without traversing.

```
traverse V.out, E.in from (SELECT FROM a) LIMIT -1`
```

Also tried playing with variants, like `WHILE $depth < 10`, but that hasn't made any difference and now I'm stuck.

Running OrientDB 2.0.12

Comment: It works for me. Is it what you were looking for ? If so, can you please mark my answer as correct ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Graph : 
[image: graph friend model representation]

Traversal query to get only the outgoing edges recursively starting from #33:289990 :

```
traverse out('IsFriendsWith') from #33:289990
```

[image: output of the traversal query]

Traversal query to get more then one edge class outgoing vertices recursively :

```
traverse out('IsFriendsWith'), out('secondEdgeClassName') from #33:289990
```

Traversal query to get the edge and vertex instances recursively :

```
traverse out('IsFriendsWith'), outE('IsFriendsWith') from #33:289990
```

Comment: `TRAVERSE out('xxx')` only returns the traversed vertices, but not the edges.

However, this gave me the missing hint. I tried `TRAVERSE out('xxx'), outE('xxx')` so now I can get both edges and vertices :)

Comment: Ok cool, I added the query at the end of the answer. I tought you only wanted the vertices :p Can you please mark my answer as correct now ? :3

Comment: I edited your anwer as well saying you want the edges as well in the output :p