# OrientDB 2.1.3: traversing edges with constraints

Tags: orientdb

I have detected a weird behaviour of `in( )`, `out( )` and `TRAVERSE` when working with constrained edges. 
Given the following DB:

```
CREATE CLASS Employee EXTENDS V;
CREATE PROPERTY Employee.nt_account String;

CREATE CLASS ManagedBy EXTENDS E;
CREATE PROPERTY ManagedBy.out LINK Employee;
CREATE PROPERTY ManagedBy.In LINK Employee;

CREATE INDEX Employee.nt_account unique_hash_index;

CREATE VERTEX Employee SET nt_account = 'e0';
CREATE VERTEX Employee SET nt_account = 'e1';
CREATE VERTEX Employee SET nt_account = 'e2';

CREATE EDGE ManagedBy FROM (SELECT FROM Employee WHERE nt_account = 'e0') TO (SELECT FROM Employee WHERE nt_account = 'e1');
CREATE EDGE ManagedBy FROM (SELECT FROM Employee WHERE nt_account = 'e1') TO (SELECT FROM Employee WHERE nt_account = 'e2');
CREATE EDGE ManagedBy FROM (SELECT FROM Employee WHERE nt_account = 'e2') TO (SELECT FROM Employee WHERE nt_account = 'e0');
```

Running a query similar to the one found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31561945/traverse-directed-edges-recursively-with-orientdb):

```
TRAVERSE out('ManagedBy') FROM (SELECT FROM Employee where nt_account = 'e0')
```

returns only one record: the entry of `e0`. The problem persists if I substitute the `SELECT` subquery with e0's RID. Similar things happen when selecting `out('ManagedBy')`.
Interestingly, the same queries in a database with the same structure but without the constraints on `ManagedBy` return the right result.

Does anybody know what's wrong with my code? (or, have I found a bug?)

Moreover, does anybody know how I can write an OSQL query that detects loops in a graph? In Cypher I would write

```
MATCH p=(e: Employee)-[:MANAGED_BY*]->(e)
RETURN p
```

---

I got good advice for the first part of the question both from @wolf4ood and @LucaS. I marked the first answer as correct (FCFS) but I think the second one too works.
As for the query, I solved it myself:

```
SELECT out.nt_account, shortestPath(in, out, 'OUT').nt_account 
FROM ManagedBy
```

As trivial as it can seem, it took me a while to write it. The trick I used is to iterate directly on the edges and check if there is a shortest path exiting from the target node and going to the source node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default properties are case sensitive

http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/SQL-Alter-Property.html

you create **in** property as **In**

```
CREATE PROPERTY ManagedBy.In LINK Employee;
```

the traverse command is expecting an **in** property. So the traversing process return only the starting node.

Change this statement in

```
CREATE PROPERTY ManagedBy.in LINK Employee;
```

and it will work

Comment: aaargh, my bad. Sorry for bothering for just a typo. Thanks for the advice. Do you have, by chance, any idea about the query I mentioned at the end of the post?

Answer (score 2):

I tried your DB and out() doesn't work, but in() yes instead.
I declared 'ManagedBy.out' with the "O" uppercase and now 'out()' works.

```
CREATE PROPERTY ManagedBy.Out LINK Employee
```

[image]

Comment: That's a bit confusing (cfr the previous answer), so which is the right capitalisation of "in" and "out" properties? "In" and "Out" or "in" and "out"?

Comment: btw, do you have, by chance, any clue about the query I mentioned?